# How to customize default pin marker using Google Cluster Manager?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

How to customize default NOT CLUSTER, but red pin marker using Google Cluster Manager? There are some similar questions around but no working answer.
When I using:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "my_marker")
        marker.setIconSize(scaledToSize: .init(width: 18, height: 24))

}
```

It customizes clusters and icons too. How to customize pin marker only not cluster marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marker` has a property `iconView` which is a UIView. Since it's a UIView you can customize however you want.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
    marker.iconView = MyView()
}
```

Comment: the effect is same as using "icon" property - the cluster image and pin marker image are iconView. I want to have default marker for clusters and my custom image pin marker - to get rid from default red pin google marker. How to distinguish them?

Comment: In your `didRenderMarker` check if `marker.userData` is type `GMUStaticCluster`. If it is, then you know it's a cluster marker. Then you can toggle your marker view accordingly.

Comment: I've done it in `willRenderMarker`. That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Works in Swift 5

[image]

```
class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
  var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var name: String!
  var icon: UIImage

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, icon: UIImage) {
    self.position = position
    self.name = name
    self.icon = icon
  }
}

class PrincipalViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.google_map.clear()

        let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
        let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
        let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: self.google_map, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        renderer.delegate = self
        self.clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: self.google_map, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
        self.clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)


        //insert your markers type POIItem
        //self.clusterManager.add(item)

        self.clusterManager.cluster()
    }

}

extension PrincipalViewController: GMUClusterRendererDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

        if marker.userData is POIItem {

            if let item = marker.userData as? POIItem {
                marker.icon = item.icon
                marker.title = item.name
            }

        }

        if marker.userData is GMUStaticCluster {

            if let staticCluster = marker.userData as? GMUStaticCluster {

                //this is a custom UIView (.xib) contain a UIImage with custom marker and one label (countLabel) where show number of grouped markers
                let customClusterMarker:CustomClusterMarker = CustomClusterMarker()

                customClusterMarker.countLabel.text = "\(staticCluster.count)"

                let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 52, height: 70))

                view.addSubview(customClusterMarker)
                marker.iconView = view

            }
        }


    }
}

extension PrincipalViewController: GMUClusterManagerDelegate {
    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap clusterItem: GMUClusterItem) -> Bool {
        print("didTap clusterItem")
        return true
    }

    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {
        print("didTap cluster")
        return true
     }
}
```